# Newtonsoft JConverter<T> to read an object or array (oneOf)

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a requirement to deserialize JSON where the sender can send either a single instance of `Child` as one of the nodes, or a `Child[]`. (a.k.a JsonSchema 'oneOf`).

```
public class Parent
{
  public Child[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
  public string ChildName { get; set; }
}
```

Where the JSON can be either an array

```
{
  "data":
    [
      {
        "childName": "Bob"
      }
    ]
}
```

or a single object

```
{
  "data":
    {
      "childName": "Bob"
    }
}
```

This is what I have so far

```
public class ObjectToArrayConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(T[]);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
        {
            JObject singleJObject = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
            return new T[] { singleJObject.Value<T>() };
        }
        var arrayJObject = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
        return arrayJObject.Value<T[]>();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Which I use like so

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings();
settings.Converters.Add(new ObjectToArrayConverter<Child>());
var parent = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Parent>(json, settings);
```

But when the JSON `data` node is a single object, the line `return new T[] { jObject.Value<T>() };` gives me the exception

System.InvalidCastException: 'Cannot cast Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject to Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.'

And when the JSON `data` node is an array of objects, the line `var arrayJObject = (JObject)serializer.Deserialize(reader);` gives me the exception

System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray' to type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the issue here is that you are using the extension method `Value` instead of `ToObject`. Value converts the "value" part of the data so in your case "Bob". ToObject converts whole object `{"childName":"Bob"}` to provided class.

```
    return arrayJObject.ToObject<T[]>(); //This should work and...
    return new T[] { singleJObject.ToObject<T>() };
```

Also, I would suggest changing to this - so it would be more readable

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    var result = (JToken)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    if (result == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(result));
    }

    if (result.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        return new T[] { result.ToObject<T>() };
    }
    else if(result.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        return result.ToObject<T[]>();
    }
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you!